# I want to learn microservice architecture. Do you have any information about .Net Core microservice architecture?

Tags: .net

I want to learn microservice architecture. Do you have any information about .Net Core microservice architecture?

Comment: See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/microservices-architecture

Answer (score 0):

If you know Restful Services, you just understand what Api Gateway is. In .NET Core you can use Ocelot Gateway for management of microservices traffic.

If you dont know restful services so you can start with that point. Then, you will see microservices means more then one restful service and an api gateway.

Comment: I know Restful Services and Api Ocelot Gateway